# oracle sql: collect aggregation

Tags: oracle, plsql, group-by, collect

I want to group my database entries by an attribute and to know which entries are in each group at the same time. I collect the ids of the grouped entries with Oracle COLLECT function [COLLECT Function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions024.htm#SQLRF06304)

```
DECLARE
  TYPE ids_type IS TABLE OF number(19, 0);   
  ids ids_type;
BEGIN 
  select cast(collect(r.id) as ids_type) into ids from rechnungsdaten r group by r.status;
END;
```

But then I get the error:

> Error report - 
>  ORA-06550: Line 5, Column 44:
>  PL/SQL:
>   ORA-00902: Invalid datatype
>  ORA-06550: Line 5, Column 5:
>   PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
>   06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>   *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
>   *Action:

What is wrong here?

Comment: To begin with, why are you declaring a type for `number(19,0)`. Second, you need to present how `rechnungsdaten` looks like (table definition).

Comment: I corrected that, now it is a list of numbers: TYPE ids_type IS TABLE OF number(19, 0);  Rechnungsdaten has many attributes, but status is a varchar2(35 char) and id is a number(19, 0)

Comment: Well, in your select statement you are attempting to convert a value (`r.id) into a table type. That, of course, is NOT a legal statement.

Comment: I am doing it using the collect function like it is described in collect documentation, isn't that correct?

Comment: Well, if you want to populate a local table with the contents of a column in another table, you can simply use the sequence `INSERT INTO .... SELECT xyz FROM ...`. In ORACLE you can have nested tables (i.e. a table column can be a table in itself), and I guess that's the main usage of the `COLLECT` function (this is just a guess and I might be wrong).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use `COLLECT` function on a type declared in a PL/SQL anonymous  block.
You have other options like

Create a database type  and run your collect query.

```
create or replace TYPE ids_type IS TABLE OF number(19, 0);
SELECT
    r.status,
    CAST(COLLECT(r.id) AS ids_type)
FROM
    rechnungsdaten r
GROUP BY
    r.status;
```

Use a simple `LISTAGG` query to see the list of ids as a string

```
SELECT
    r.status,
    LISTAGG(r.id,',') WITHIN GROUP(
            ORDER BY
                id
        )
FROM
    rechnungsdaten r
GROUP BY
    r.status;
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5c6a7/1)